# How to specify array of class in GetMethodID method signature parameter?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

How do I specify in `GetMethodID` function signature parameter that the function I am getting id for accepts array of a custom class?

I have one function in java with signature:

```
void getData( ListDataClass[] arryData )
```

And i want to get the method id of this function from the JNI interface using GetMethodID function.
For that i have mentioned in function signature parameter as following:

```
"([myPackeg/ListDataClass)V"
```

But this is not working and i get exception as `Method Not Found`.  Same thing works if i specify array of string class.

Comment: Are you calling from the main thread or from a different thread? If you're calling from a different thread (such as a thread you've created inside your native code) you will need to do additional things.

Comment: @Alex what do you mean saying additional things? I'm calling from different thread and something's wrong.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

JNI type signatures for fully-qualified-classes take the form:

```
Lclass/path/ClassName;
```

For example:

```
"Ljava/lang/String;" // String
"[Ljava/lang/String;" // String[] (array)
```

A method signature is built up from these by placing arguments within parentheses first and the return type after the right bracket. For example:

```
long f (int n, String s, int[] arr); // Java method
"(ILjava/lang/String;[I)J" // JNI type signature
```

You can find the docs for for JNI type signatures [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp276), which is where I borrowed the above example from.

In your specific example:

```
void getData( ListDataClass[] arryData ) // Java method
"([Lclass/path/ListDataClass;)V" // JNI type signature
```

Note: the exact type signature depends on your class path.

You can then find the method ID as follows (assuming C++ and a JNIEnv pointer called env):

```
jclass clz = env->FindClass("class/path/ListDataClass");
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(clz, "getData", "([Lclass/path/ListDataClass;)V");
```

Comment: you have a typo there: `([Lclass/path/ListDataClass;)V`, not `(L[class/path/ListDataClass;)V`